# Can't add a marker in this code anyhow

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have tried to use traditional marker function with this code but the marker is not visible. How can I add marker attached to this info window.

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 22.5726,
            lng: 88.3639
        },
        zoom: 13
    });

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent("You're here Bro!");

            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation 
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }

    new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

Comment: where is the code that you have added for marker?

Comment: There is nothing in the posted code to add a marker.  What did you do that didn't work?

Comment: I used the code -> var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: pos,
          map: map,
});  -> before infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;   but it didnt worked

Comment: I get an error with the posted code:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: AutocompleteDirectionsHandler is not defined` on this line: `new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);`.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  With the code in your previous comment, I get a different javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: pos is not defined` (because it isn't defined there)

Comment: I used a code like the answer below and it dosent work

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the marker component

Use the below code.

```js
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: 22.5726, lng: 88.3639},,
          map: map,
          title: 'Text to show on mouseover on this marker'
});
```

Comment: This is for marker code i was mentioning about and the marker here will be on particular lat lng but i want the marker where the infowindow is appearing

Comment: @Aritraghosal can you add screenshot of the expected and actual results. I am still not getting, where you want the marker